# UTF8.GetString strips special character (0xd 0xa)

Tags: c#

I am using UTF8.GetString to read context from inbound stream, store it to database varchar typed column, but it seems I am missing the special character 0xd 0xa. How can I correct this?

Thanks advance for the help!

edit: inbound stream is represented in bytes

Comment: can't you use nvarchar instead ?

Comment: I assume you're using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[], int, int)` to get the string from an incoming array of bytes. Are you sure that the 0x0d and 0x0a characters are included in the range of bytes you're converting?  If they're at the end of a line, it's common to strip them from the string when reading.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a single character - that's two characters, "carriage return" U+000D and "line feed" U+000A... and the UTF-8 decoder can certainly handle them. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bytes = { 0x41, 0xd, 0xa, 0x42 };
        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(text == "A\r\nB");
    }
}
```

Are you sure your database isn't stripping the characters? Or if you've got XML input, perhaps that's stripping it, believing it to be ignorable whitespace?

Comment: Got it, it was my mistake i did a copy and paste from SQL serever result pane, apparently it does not copy the line feed for some reason